# LESS - Mathematics to set position

Tags: html, css, less, css-position, fuelux

Is there anyway that I can code classes in less so that each element with the same class will minus 56px from the previous sibling?

An example of my code so far is below:

```
.complete {
    position:absolute

    &[data-step="1"] { left:-725px; }
    &[data-step="2"] { left:-669px; }
    &[data-step="3"] { left:-613px; }
    &[data-step="4"] { left:-557px; }

}
```

This doesn't seem to be an efficient way of doing things as there could be an instance when there might be more than 4 steps. I could use nth-child but then this also relates to whether there are more than 4 steps.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: While you can use Less loops to avoid code repetition, it still cannot help if the no. of elements is an unknown number. You would have to statically generate as many classes as the max no. of elements possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [loop](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature). This should work for your case:

```
.loop(@counter) when (@counter > 0) {
  .loop((@counter - 1));
  &[data-step="@{counter}"] { left:(-725 + (@counter - 1) * 56px); }
}

.complete {
    position:absolute;
    .loop(4);
}
```

Comment: That is amazing, thanks so much! The only problem I have found is that for some reason, the loop is generating a space between -725 and px so the value is throwing an error in chrome dev tools. Is there anyway to remove the space? I've tried the below way but it doesn't seem to work:

.loop(@counter) when (@counter > 0) {
  .loop((@counter - 1));
  &[data-step="@{counter}"] {
      left:(-725+(@counter - 1)*56)px;
  }
}

Comment: Not to worry, I've worked it out, I needed to move the px inside the parenthesis :)